# Display name of table instead of its id Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables, `tn_project` has id name `cv_id_project` and `tn_activity` has id name `id`, i want to get the name of the project which is `cv_project_name` rather its `id`.

Basically when i click `add activity` i have `select` option to choose which `project` that i use, i manage to get the id of selected `project` but i want its `name`(i can select up to 3 `project` in a single `activity`)

> Model

```
<?php namespace Activity;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Activity extends Model {
    protected $table = 'tn_activity';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function projectModel(){
       return $this->hasMany('Activity\Project','cv_id_project','id');
   }
}
```

> VIEW

```
@foreach($query as $result)
    <td>{{$result->projectModel->cv_project_name}}</td>
@endforeach
```

> Controller

```
public function index(){
    return view('landing-page')
        ->with('title','Landing Page')
        ->with('query',Activity::with('projectModel')->get())
        ->with('projects',Project::all());
}
```

usually it's work but i don't know what makes it error
and then this error occured

> `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$cv_project_name (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\PKL\netxcel-2-backup2\resources\views\landing-page.blade.php)`

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity `projectModel` is a collection, because it has hasMany relationship. If it's really true, you should get the project name like this.

```
@foreach ($result->projectModel as $project)
    <td>{{$project->cv_project_name}}</td>
@endforeach
```

However, if it shouldn't have hasMany relationship than you should change the hasMany part

Comment: what if it's belongsTo?

Comment: it's not working, i don't know but i think we can't have foreach inside a foreach, take a look at my view code again

Comment: how about `$query->projectModel as $project` in the foreach

Comment: The problem is the projectModel is a collection thus you can't get cv_project_name of it since it's an attribute of Project.

Comment: So the one that should be looped is the projectModel

Comment: Can I see the latest piece code? The one that have `->cv_project_name`

Comment: `@foreach ($query->projectModel as $project)` inside its `{{$project->cv_project_name}} @endforeach`

Comment: How about this?
`@foreach ($query as $activity)`
    `@foreach ($activity->projectModel as $project)`
         `{{$project->cv_project_name}}`

Comment: Could you please provide more detail about your database schema and the ouptut of:
`@foreach ($query->projectModel as $project) {{ dd($project) }} @endforeach`